# Where in clause with a at least one element of a list

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, criteria, restriction

I've got the following problem:

I've three classes, each class map a table on my db. The situation is the following:

```
class A{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Set<AB> ab = new HashSet<AB>(0);
    //getter and setter
}

class AB{
   Integer id;
   A a;
   B b;
   //getter and setter
}

class B{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Set<AB> ab = new HashSet<AB>(0);

    //getter and setter
}
```

And I want to realize using Hibernate Criteria, the following query:

```
" Select * from B b join b.ab where  ab.a.id in (id1 or id2 or id3)".
```

In other words I want that in the where clause, at least one of the element. I've tried something like this:

```
Session session  = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.in(ab, input.getAb));
```

But it seems doesn't work as expecting, seems it looking for all object of the set are equals.

Some tips to solve this question?

Thanks in advance